# Text decoration on scroll to top javascript code

Tags: javascript, scroll, text-decorations

I have a link at the bottom of my page with

```
    <a href="javascript:scroll(0,0)">
Online Marketing
</a>
```

To scroll to top of page but it makes the text blue and underlined how do i add some code to remove text deceration to it?

i tried `a href="javascript:scroll(0,0)" style="text-decoration: none; color:#FFFFFF;">` 
but then the scroll to top stopped working does anyone now any way to get round this to remove the text deceration using code on the specific element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks right...which is odd. Perhaps try assigning the scroll button to a CSS class.

In your style sheet add

```
a.StandardTextLink:link, a.StandardTextLink:active, a.StandardTextLink:visited {text-decoration:none;color:#FFF;}
```

Then in your html

```
<a href="javascript:scroll(0,0)" class="StandardTextLink">Scroll to top</a>
```

Hopefully that'll sort it.

C

Answer (score 1):

You could try not using an element that has default styles:

```
<span onClick="scroll(0,0);" style="cursor: pointer;">Online Marketing</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check spelling of your style-attribute, especially quotas. Expression should work.